# How to download WebView.dll from windows mobile to desktop

Tags: windows-mobile, activex, download, webbrowser-control

To host Webview (Web Browser Webview.dll) ActiveX control in C# smart device application, we need to download and access  WebView.dll present in Windows mobile 6.0, 6.1, 6.5 version in root windows directory (\Windows\WebView.dll).

Currently we are unable to download the WebView.dll from mobile device, please guide us further.

Regards,
Ramanand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably cannot do that because it's not a physical file, just a piece of data mounted as one. It's a Windows CE legacy, I guess.

Comment: Thanks. yes it is Windows CE legacy.